# How can I seal holes in a roof after moving an air conditioner?

Tags: roof

On a single story flat roof private home I need to move a rooftop air conditioning radiator 20 cm for a solar panel install. Fortunately the original install left enough electrical cable and refrigerant hose dangling whereas I do not need to concern myself with them. All I need to do is remove the four bolts in the roof, remount in the new location, and seal the original holes.

The house was constructed in 2017. The roof is concrete with a tar-like blanket on top. I do not know how thick the blanket or roof are.

**How should I seal the original holes?**

Comment: Aside - calling the previous install "sloppy" might be harsh.  Instead, they've chosen to leave a service loop specifically to allow a cable/wire tolerance for later work.   I always leave some slack cable where possible.

Comment: @Criggie Thank you for that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Clean out the old holes as good as possible and get a dry or wet patch from your home store and press it into the holes... tamp it in with a nail until the hole is filled.